# How use a preset WINE prefix during the installation on POL?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I'm trying to run a game which need to be run under a 32-bit prefix (due to component needed).

I succeeded in creating the folder; the problem is as I'm setting up the program POL installed it as default in a automatically-generated wine prefix (64-bit due to my config).

How can I install my game in a pre-existing prefix? Or Maybe did I miss a step and you can choose it during the installation but I did not find it?

I can choose either the 32 or 64 before the installation using POL but then when I try to add components to it I get something like `unable to set it in a 64-bit virtual drive`.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a pre-existing prefix (*aka* virtual drive) by clicking the Configure button, then clicking on the prefix in the left pane. After that, I think you pick the fifth tab and then click 'Run EXE in this virtual drive' and select your installer EXE (if possible).

However it's possible that it's not installing in 32-bit because you don't have 32-bit Wine? Try clicking Tools, then Manage Wine versions, then click a Wine version from Available Wine versions on the left (in the Wine versions (x86) tab), then clicking the > arrow.

Comment: i succeed to create the 32-bit virtual drive and I installed the components... But my .exe does not appear in the list when i click on "launch an .exe in this virtual drive" :(

Comment: When i try to run it since the console in the POL environment it tells me "command not found"

Comment: @JaneDoe sounds to me like a bug that you can file [here](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/bugs.html)